# setState implementation in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I was checking the ReactJS tutorial at https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html and got confused at following point:
When we want to update the current state based on previous state we should invoke a variant of setState which takes a function

```
this.setState(function(prevState, props) {
  return {
    counter: prevState.counter + props.increment
  };
});
```

Now my question is who will invoke this function now with previous state ? As in if we call the setState directly with values we know that we have triggered the workflow to set the state to value. However in this case, who will invoke this method and how does it know what are the params to pass as this is a dynamic method ?

Comment: setState accepts object and function as argument. you can use ```this.setState(() => { myState: 'newState' })``` and would still be the same as ```this.setState({ myState: 'newState' })```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setState` function will call the function.

**For Example** *(Not he actual setState function just to show the concept)*

```
var setState = function(param) {
  var newState;
  if(typeof param === 'function') {
    newState = param(prevState); // run function that passed and get the returned object
    // set new state with newState
  }
  else {
    newState = param; // use passed object
  }

  // set new state with newState

}

setState(function(prevState) { return { some: 'Value' }; });
setState({ some: 'Value'});
```

Comment: Ok, but here, param can be a function with different kind of inputs, right ? Or is it fixed the input params that it can receive ? So, basically how setState knows which input args to pass ?

Comment: The function that you passed will be called with the prevState object.

Comment: but in the tutorial, they have defined a function which takes both prevState and Props ?

Comment: well prevState and props. Correct.

Answer (score 2):

The current signature of `setState`

1. **setState({state_name : value})**
2. **setState(nextState, callback)**
3. **setState(callback)**

There are some points to remember while using `setState`

1. There is no guarantee that `this.state` will be immediately updated, so
   accessing `this.state` after calling this method may return the old 
   value.Because React may batch multiple `setState()` calls into a single update for performance.

**e.g. Below one is wrong as there is no guarantee that `this.state.counter` is updated one.**

```
assuming count=1 initially.

this.setState({
  counter: this.state.counter + 1
});

this.setState({
  counter: this.state.counter + 1
});
```

`counter =1 and not 3 as`

**It’s safe to assume that `setState` is  asynchronous.**

To fix it, use other  form of `setState()` that accepts a function(callback) rather than an object

When a function is provided to `setState`, React will be called it at some point in
the future (**not synchronously**). It will be called with the up to date
component arguments (`state, props, context`).

Using third signature

```
assuming count=1 initially.

    this.setState((state)=>({counter: state.counter + 1}))
    this.setState((state)=>({counter: state.counter + 1}))

counter = 3
```